# Using accessible_by with CanCan is not generating the correct SQL statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

In the app I am building, a User has the ability to add "Contributors" to their account to help them fill out certain aspects of their profile for them. I am using `cancan` to help facilitate defining abilities but for some reason the query that is returned for a contributor and which users they have access too is not coming back correctly.

Here is my Ability file:

```
module Abilities
  class UserAbility < Ability
    def initialize(user)
      super(user)

      if user.athlete_contributor?
        can :update, Athlete, user: { id: user.managed_athlete_ids }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

User Model:

```
  has_many :contributorships
  has_many :managed_athletes, through: :contributorships, source: :athlete
```

Contributorship Model:

```
class Contributorship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :athlete
  belongs_to :contributor, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :user_type

  attr_accessible :user_id, :user_type_id, :athlete_id

  validates :user_type, presence: true 
end
```

Contributor Dashboard Controller:

```
class ContributorController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    authorize! :update, Athlete
    @athletes = Athlete.accessible_by(current_ability)
  end

end
```

The `@athletes` instance variable is returning a query of

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Athlete') AND ('t'='f')
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but that query looks busted, LOL. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. "Accessible_by" built me a wrong WHERE condition, but it was solved when I upgraded cancan to version 1.6.10.

I hope this can :help @you ;)